# What is the fastest way to transform a very large JSON file with Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am having a rather large JSON file ([Amazon product data](http://jmcauley.ucsd.edu/data/amazon/)) with a lot of single JSON objects. Those JSON objects contain text that I want to preprocess for a specific training task but it is the preprocessing that I need to speed up here. One JSON object looks like this:

```
{
  "reviewerID": "A2SUAM1J3GNN3B",
  "asin": "0000013714",
  "reviewerName": "J. McDonald",
  "helpful": [2, 3],
  "reviewText": "I bought this for my husband who plays the piano.  He is having a wonderful time playing these old hymns.  The music  is at times hard to read because we think the book was published for singing from more than playing from.  Great purchase though!",
  "overall": 5.0,
  "summary": "Heavenly Highway Hymns",
  "unixReviewTime": 1252800000,
  "reviewTime": "09 13, 2009"
}
```

The task would be to extract `reviewText` from each JSON object and perform some preprocessing like lemmatizing etc.

My problem is that I don't know how I could use Spark in order to speed this task up on a cluster.. I am actually not even sure if I can read that JSON file as a stream object-by-object and parallelize the main task.

What would be the best way to get started with this?

Comment: Parallelizing a single JSON isn't possible unless you change the way you're receiving the JSON. But why would you want to do that? Have your JSON serializer only deserialize the `reviewText` property using `RDD.map`, which can spread the JSONs between your cluster nodes.

Comment: Do your JSON objects span across multiple lines in file? If yes, does "reviewText" field along with it's value always occupy single line? I'm trying to understand if it's possible to extract all values from "reviewText" using simple `filter` `map` and regexps.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Actually, and I didn't noticed until now, the data is such that per line there is *one* JSON element. So using simply `map` would already utilize all nodes available?

Comment: @Aivean It appears that I am lucky and that the file is already prepared as one JSON object per line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have single JSON object per line, you can use `RDD`'s `textFile` to get `RDD[String]` of lines. Then use `map` to parse JSON objects using something like [json4s](https://github.com/json4s/json4s) and extract necessary field.

You whole code will looks as simple as this (assuming you have `SparkContext` as `sc`):

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
implicit def formats = DefaultFormats

val r  = sc.textFile("input_path").map(l => (parse(l) \ "reviewText").extract[String])
```

Comment: I really start to like Spark :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JSON dataset and then execute a simple sql query to retrieve the `reviewText` column's value:

```
// A JSON dataset is pointed to by path.
// The path can be either a single text file or a directory storing text files.
val path = "path/reviews.json"
val people = sqlContext.read.json(path)
// Register this DataFrame as a table.
people.registerTempTable("reviews")
val reviewTexts = sqlContext.sql("SELECT reviewText FROM reviews")
```

Built from examples at the SparkSQL docs (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#json-datasets)

Answer (score -2):

I would load JSON data into Dataframe and then select field that i need, also you can use map to apply preprocessing like lemmatising.